# Very high memory usage in these Digit Analysis (Hash) algorithms in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory, hash

I have an university exercise, where I have to compare some hashing methods with their number of colisions in the hash table. Then I made theses Digit Analysis algorithms, but they are using A LOT of memory (I can't even run the code until the end, because it kills my computer). You can ignore the comments, but fell free if you want and knows portuguese.

**Digit Analysis function 1 (Using dinamic matrix)**

```c
int hashUVDigitAnalysis(int len, int value, int numofdigits, int *arr){
    int keydigits, *digits = getDigits(value, &keydigits);

    if(numofdigits >= keydigits){
        free(digits);                                                        //                                     -ATENÇÃO-
        return value;                                                        //
    }else{                                                                   // Essa função funciona, mas quando testei com o vetor *arr muito grande, ele rapidamente
        int **numqntmatrix = (int **)(malloc(10 * sizeof(int *)));           //          consumiu maior parte da memória do meu pc, e o computador falhou por
        int cont1, cont2, countdigits;                                       //                    falta de memória. Use essa função apenas para
        float *detours = (float *)(malloc(keydigits * sizeof(float)));       //                            testar um único valor (UV).
                                                                             // Como alternativa, tentei realizar a função abaixo desta, mas a mesma deu o mesmo problema.
        for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < 10; cont1++){                                 //
            numqntmatrix[cont1] = (int *)(malloc(keydigits * sizeof(int)));
            for(cont2 = 0; cont2 < keydigits; cont2++){
                numqntmatrix[cont1][cont2] = 0;
            }
        }

        for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < len; cont1++){
            digits = getDigits(arr[cont1], &countdigits);
            for(cont2 = 0; cont2 < keydigits && cont2 < countdigits; cont2++){
                numqntmatrix[digits[cont2]][cont2] += 1;
            }
        }

        for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < keydigits; cont1++){
            detours[cont1] = 0.0;
        }

        for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < keydigits; cont1++){
            for(cont2 = 0; cont2 < 10; cont2++){
                detours[cont1] += (numqntmatrix[cont2][cont1] - (len / 10.0)) * (numqntmatrix[cont2][cont1] - (len / 10.0));
            }
        }

        for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < 10; cont1++){
            free(numqntmatrix[cont1]);
        }
        free(numqntmatrix);

        int *concatenate = (int *)(malloc(numofdigits * sizeof(int)));

        for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < numofdigits; cont1++){
            cont2 = 0;
            concatenate[cont1] = cont2;
            for(cont2 = 1; cont2 < keydigits; cont2++){
                if(detours[cont2] < detours[concatenate[cont1]] && detours[cont2] != -1){
                    concatenate[cont1] = cont2;
                }
            }
            detours[concatenate[cont1]] = -1;
        }

        digits = getDigits(value, &countdigits);
        int valueposition = 0;

        for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < numofdigits; cont1++){
            valueposition += digits[concatenate[cont1]] * pow(10, cont1);
        }

        free(detours);
        free(digits);

        return valueposition;
    }
}
```

**Digit Analysis function 2 (Using only arrays)**

```c
int hashQuadraticDigitAnalysis(int len, int value, int numofdigits, int *arr){
    int keydigits, *digits = getDigits(value, &keydigits);

    if(numofdigits >= keydigits){
        free(digits);
        return value;
    }else{
        int cont1, cont2, countdigits;
        int *numbers = (int *)(malloc(10 * sizeof(int)));
        float *detours = (float *)(malloc(10 * sizeof(float)));

        for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < 10; cont1++){
            numbers[cont1] = 0;
            detours[cont1] = 0.0;
        }

        for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < 10; cont1++){
            for(cont2 = 0; cont2 < len; cont2++){
                digits = getDigits(arr[cont2], &countdigits);
                if(cont1 < countdigits){
                    numbers[digits[cont1]] += 1;
                }
            }
            for(cont2 = 0; cont2 < 10; cont2++){
                detours[cont1] += (numbers[cont2] - (len / 10.0)) * (numbers[cont2] - (len / 10.0));
                numbers[cont2] = 0;
            }
        }

        int *concatenate = (int *)(malloc(numofdigits * sizeof(int)));

        for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < numofdigits; cont1++){
            cont2 = 0;
            concatenate[cont1] = cont2;
            for(cont2 = 1; cont2 < keydigits; cont2++){
                if(detours[cont2] < detours[concatenate[cont1]] && detours[cont2] != -1){
                    concatenate[cont1] = cont2;
                }
            }
            detours[concatenate[cont1]] = -1;
        }

        digits = getDigits(value, &countdigits);
        int valueposition = 0;

        for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < numofdigits; cont1++){
            valueposition += digits[concatenate[cont1]] * pow(10, cont1);
        }

        free(concatenate);
        free(detours);
        free(digits);

        return valueposition;
    }
}
```

**getDigits function**

```c
int* getDigits(int value, int *addr_countdigits){
    int copyofvalue = value;
    *addr_countdigits = 0;

    while(copyofvalue != 0){
        copyofvalue = copyofvalue / 10;
        *addr_countdigits = *addr_countdigits + 1;
    }

    int tmp = *addr_countdigits;
    int *array = (int *)(malloc(tmp * sizeof(int)));
    copyofvalue = value;

    while(copyofvalue > 0){
        array[tmp - 1] = copyofvalue % 10;
        copyofvalue = copyofvalue / 10;
        tmp = tmp-1;
    }

    return array;
}
```

**Main**

```c
int main(void){
    int len = 100000, lenarr = 200000, cont, random, numcolision = 0, pos;

    int *randomarr = (int *)(malloc(lenarr * sizeof(int)));

    int *hash_division = (int *)(malloc(len * sizeof(int)));

    for(cont = 0; cont < len; cont++){
        hash_division[cont] = -1;
    }

    for(cont = 0; cont < lenarr; cont++){
        random  = (((rand() & 255)<<8 | (rand() & 255))<<8 | (rand() & 255))<<7 | (rand() & 127);
        random = random % 2000000001;
        randomarr[cont] = random;
    }

    for(cont = 0; cont < lenarr; cont++){
        pos = hashUVDigitAnalysis(lenarr, randomarr[cont], 5, randomarr);
        if(hash_division[pos] == -1){
            hash_division[pos] = randomarr[cont];
        } else{
            numcolision++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", numcolision);
    return 0;
}
```

I have 14 GB of usable RAM memory (total of 16 GB).
I tested both functions and there isn't any infinity loop. The code runs when I put `lenarr = 10000`, but I have to test with `len = 100000` and `lenarr` equals to 200 thousand, 400 thousand, 600 thousand, 800 thousand and 1 million, so only 10 thousand will not works for me. I'm doing something wrong? Is there any way to fix this? I never had a memory problem in any code before, so I'm not good with controlling my memory in code.

Comment: Can you include the definition of getDigits?

Comment: Okay, I did it. But, basically, it gets all the digits of a number and puts in an array. The `keydigits` is the quantity of digits in that number.

Comment: Use valgring and check for memory leaks. If you do not have memory leaks, then at any allocation add the amount of allocated memory to the counter and print it. See where you allocate the most. Try to debug it yourself. Looking many hours at the code will not help you at all and we also are not free debugging service. Do the hard and boring work yourself. It is your assignment, not ours

Comment: Count how many times you do `getDigits(...)`. For each `getDigits(...)`, find its own personal `free()`. Can't find one? That's your memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause of leak

I looked at this in valgrind, and it looks like you're missing five calls to free. This is the largest leak:

```
    for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < len; cont1++){
        digits = getDigits(arr[cont1], &countdigits);
        for(cont2 = 0; cont2 < keydigits && cont2 < countdigits; cont2++){
            numqntmatrix[digits[cont2]][cont2] += 1;
        }
        // free memory returned by getDigits()
        free(digits);
    }
```

Every loop through this calls `getDigits()`, which allocates memory which is never freed.

Other sources of leaks:

- `int keydigits, *digits = getDigits(value, &keydigits);`
- `int *concatenate = (int *)(malloc(numofdigits * sizeof(int)));`
- `int *randomarr = (int *)(malloc(lenarr * sizeof(int)));`
- `int *hash_division = (int *)(malloc(len * sizeof(int)));`

### How to use valgrind

Here's how I performed the valgrind analysis:

First, I reduced the number of loops the program makes from 100K to 10. This prevents it from running out of memory while valgrind is running.

Second, I compiled the program with `-ggdb`, to enable debugging information. Here's the command I used:

```
gcc test027.c -Wall -Werror -lm -ggdb -o test027
```

Third, I ran valgrind with `--leak-check=full`:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./test027
```

This showed me the stacktraces of the sources of the memory leaks. Each one looks like this:

```
==174419== 1,501,600 bytes in 40,000 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==174419==    at 0x483C7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==174419==    by 0x10925C: getDigits (test027.c:16)
==174419==    by 0x10940D: hashUVDigitAnalysis (test027.c:50)
==174419==    by 0x109988: main (test027.c:118)
```

The first thing you see is the size of the memory leak. (1,501,600 bytes). You should solve the largest memory leak first. Next, you see how many allocations were made that were never freed. (40,000 blocks). Next, you see the line numbers of the part of the program which is responsible.

Solve each memory leak one at a time, and re-run valgrind. Once you solve all the leaks, valgrind will show this output:

```
==174500== HEAP SUMMARY:
==174500==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==174500==   total heap usage: 43,003 allocs, 43,003 frees, 1,621,428 bytes allocated
==174500== 
==174500== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: Thank you, really. I didn't know Valgrid before ask this question, and I was installing it and test myself when you answered. I thought that, when I used `free (digits)` in the end of the functions, it would be OK (kinda idiot, I know). I will free all the `getDigits` and test myself the code later. Thank you again.